# Prove that: if $A$ is a retract of $X$, $H_n(X) \approx H_n(A) \oplus H_n(X,A)$, without referencing splitting.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm reading Rotman's algebraic topology and I've come across this problem:

> Prove that: if $A$ is a retract of $X$, $H_n(X) \approx  H_n(A) \oplus H_n(X,A)$.

I've seen a few questions about this already but each of the answers involve splitting, which is something that hasn't been covered in the book yet.  I've tried a lot of gritty notational attempts at showing this but it leads to a headache of indices.

Anyone have any ideas how to show this **without** referencing splitting?

Comment: What do you mean by splitting? The isomorphism of homology groups *is* a splitting.

Comment: The other questions I've seen about this all involve phrases like: "splitting", "splitting theorems", "split-injective", "...exact sequence splits".  Anything involving splitting hasn't been covered in the book yet, so I'm trying to prove this without referencing any sort of splitting.  In the book I'm in chapter 5 on long exact sequences, and the first time anything "splitting" related is in chapter 9 on natural transformations.

Comment: Then 'splitting' is algebraic rather than topological so should be external knowledge. If $i:A\rightarrow X$ is the inclusion and $r:X\rightarrow A$ is the retraction with $r\circ i=id_A$ then the induced homomorphisms satisfy $r_*\circ i_*=(r\circ i)_*=(id_A)_*=id_{H_*(A)}$. Thus in the long exact sequence of the pair, the map $i_*:H_*(A)\rightarrow H_*(X)$ is injective and the long exact sequence splits into short exact sequences $0\rightarrow H_n(A)\rightarrow H_n(X)\rightarrow H_n(X,A)\rightarrow 0$.The homomorphism $r_*$ induced by the retraction gives the splitting of each s.e. sequence.

Comment: I just had a look at the book. This is exactly one third of the splitting lemma. You get a short exact sequence like in the first part of the problem. And then you are arrived at splitting lemma. So just prove that part of splitting lemma. (Note that not every proof of splitting lemma need to contain the proof you want since there are 3 conditions which are equivalent and you need one implication). [At wiki it is 1. ⇒ 3.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma)